# Redux action not updating redux state in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Whenever I click add to cart button, the action is fired but redux state is not been updated (the initial state is not changing but the action is triggered).

```
const CartScreen = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { search } = useLocation();
    const [searchParms] = useSearchParams();
  
    const productId = id;
    const qty = search ? Number(search.split("=")[1]) : 1;
  

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
      if (productId){
        dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty))
      }
    
    }, [dispatch, productId, qty])

    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Add to CART</h1>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default CartScreen
```

Cart action

```
export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) =>{
    const {data} = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/${id}`)
    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload:{
            product:data._id,
            name:data.name,
            image:data.image,
            countInStock:data.countInStock,
            qty
        }
    })
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}
```

Cart Reducer

```
export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: []}, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
            const item = action.payload
            const existItem = state.cartItems.findIndex(x => x.product === item.product)

            if (existItem){
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x => 
                        x.product === existItem.product ? item : x)
                }
            } else{
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems:[...state.cartItems, item]
                }
            }

            default:
                return state
    }
}
```

Redux store

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,

})

const initialState = {
  cart:{cartItems:cartItemsFromStorage}
};
const middleware = [thunk];

 const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);
```

From redux dev tools I can see that the action I triggered. The item is getting to cart reducer because when I console.log `item` in `const item=action.payload` from the cartReducer, I get the particular item in Browser console, yet the cartItem redux state remains at the initial value, it's not updated

Comment: What/where is `addToCart` being dispatched? You see the `CART_ADD_ITEM` action dispatched, but the `payload` isn't working? What is the value of `data` in the action creator? What is the `payload` value in the redux dev tool? I don't see any overt issues in the `cartReducer` function that would lead me to think it's not updating the state correctly. If possible, think you could create a *running* minimal codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live? You can mock the `"/api/products/:id"` API response.

Comment: Thank you @Drew Reese. I have updated the post to include the component where I'm dispatching the action. Now, when I click add to cart the item is getting to cartReducer, meaning the payload is working. I know this because in `cartReducer` there's this expression `const item = action.payload`. when I console.log `item` and click the add to cart button I see the particular item in the browser console. In spite of that, the cartItem state is still returning an empty array in redux dev tool

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.find()- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Array.prototype.findIndex()- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Using Array.prototype.findIndex() will basically look for and return the index of the first found item, and `-1` if not found. While  Array.prototype.find() returns the first element in the array that matched the criteria provided.

```js
export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
  case CART_ADD_ITEM:
    const item = action.payload;

    // use Array.prototype.find() instead
    // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
    const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => x.product === item.product);

    if (existItem){
      return{
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x =>
          x.product === existItem.product ? item : x)
      };
    } else{
      return{
        ...state,
        cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item]
      };
    }

  default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Chigbogu. When I click on add to cart button the program is able to get the right item I'm trying to add to the cart. The action is dispatched and the item gets to the cart reducer. The issue I'm having is that despite the item being present in the cart reducer, the state is not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are searching for an existing product and returning the found index (*`array.findIndex`*) ***then*** using the index value as a boolean condition (*`if (existItem) {...}`*).

This won't work as you are expecting since all non-zero numbers are truthy, while `0` is falsey. This means if no cart item products match that `-1` is returned and the logic will treat this as an existing item. This is compounded later when updating the cart via `array.map`... if `existItem` is `-1` this means there is no matching product, the new `state.cartItems` will be a new array, but it will not contain the new `item` object. In other words it will be ***just*** a copy of the previous state.

`cartItems` starts initially as an empty array, so `existItem` will ***always*** return `-1` when first adding an item to the cart.

An additional unintentional bug occurs when a product does exist in the `cartItems` array and it's the 0th element. `existItem` will equal `0` and is thus falsey and `item` will be added to `cartItems` array as a duplicate.

@Chigbogu is correct regarding the use of `array.findIndex` and `array.find`, though I'd recommend using `array.some` if you are just checking the the cart items array has the item or not. This indicates you are working with a boolean explicitly. Rename `existItem` to `hasItem` or similar so the name also indicates a boolean value (*this is by convention*).

```
export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: []}, action) =>{
  switch(action.type) {
    case CART_ADD_ITEM: {
      const newItem = action.payload;
      const hasItem = state.cartItems.some(item => item.product === newItem.product);

      if (hasItem) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.map(item => 
            item.product === newItem.product ? newItem : item
          )
        }
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: [...state.cartItems, newItem]
        }
      }
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```